# MVC HTML ActionLink inserting a lot of %20 in the URL

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor, xdt-transform

I am using C# ASP MVC3 and I am making a generated menu with parameters passed through castle windsor.

When I was developing and tested locally, the urls generated from this code were fine:

```
  @foreach(var menuItem in Model.MenuItems)
        {
            var dic = new RouteValueDictionary();



            foreach (var item in menuItem.QueryValues)
            {
                dic.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
            }


            <li>@Html.ActionLink(menuItem.Name, menuItem.ControllerAction, dic)</li>

            }
```

But when it was pushed to the test server, the URL decided to add:

```
%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20
```

in between each parameter that was being passed through with the URL.

Not totally sure which areas to show to help with a solving the problem. Could it be the xdt:Transform:Replace used within the web.config or something totally different. Any help you can provide would be appreciated.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:** I found what was causing all of these spaces in the link that was being generated. The XML replace was adding in returns and spaces in the XML file when it was doing the replace. I'm going to leave this question open for now, as it's not ideal that this is happening, so the question has sort of changed to how do we stop the xdt:Replace from adding in these unwanted spaces and returns?

Comment: `%20` is the HTML encoding for an empty space. Are you sure that the parameters you're using don't have empty spaces?

Comment: Additionally to what @AndreCalil commented, `%0D%0A` encode a Windows linebreak.

Comment: @Oded That's a good point, I've ignored that part. David, are you using the same data source locally and at the test server?

Comment: It is all coming from the web.config file. I am using xml-document-transform to allow each environment to have its own configuration, so that is `<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">` in the main configuration tag with `<castle xdt:Transform="Replace">` in the tags that I need to replace. Locally, this doesn't generate these spaces and line breaks. I have tried rejigging the formatting within the menu itself and the xml to no avail

Comment: I found what the problem was. I went and inspected the web.config files on the server, and it had added in spaces and returns that are not there normally when doing the replace operation. I edited these on the fly on the server and it seemed to resolve the problem in link generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After speaking to a few people and doing a LOT of searching, I have found that this is a bug within visual studio 2010 before SP1. As the machine that is building and publishing the app hasn't got SP1 installed (It is due for an upgrade though) that this was the problem.

To make the bug a none factor, I added a TrimEnd for the characters " ", "\r", "\n" to remove any white space from the items that are being replaced.

Comment: I've got this bug in VS2015 too. No idea what the fix is yet.

Answer (score 2):

So the actual answer lies in [this post](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/18701285/2020-is-being-added-to-end-of-actionlink). The nchar type has spaces on the end, which are encoded to HTTP by Asp.net as '%20'.