# %20%20... is being added to end of actionlink

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, actionlink

I'm trying to create a link to edit each entry in a web grid but when I click on the link it append "`%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20`" to the end of the url. I have no idea why this is happening. The link works find if I remove the "`%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20`" in the browser address bar.

```
<div class="divGridHistory">
     @historyDataGrid.GetHtml("webGridStyle",
        rowStyle: "gridrow",
        alternatingRowStyle: "altgridrow",
        selectedRowStyle: "webGridSelectedRow",
        displayHeader: true,
        htmlAttributes: new { id = "dedDetailDataGrid" },
        columns: historyDataGrid.Columns(
            historyDataGrid.Column("ControlGroupId", "Control Group ID", style: "webGridGroupId"),
            historyDataGrid.Column("OrganizationId", "Organization ID", style: "webGridOrganizationId"),
            historyDataGrid.Column("AleIndicator", "ALE Indicator", style: "webGridAleIndicator"),
            historyDataGrid.Column("EffectiveDate","Effective Date", style: "webGridStartDate", format: item => @Utility.FormatShortDate(item.EffectiveDate)),
            historyDataGrid.Column("ChangeReason","Change Reason", style: "webGridChangeReason"),
            historyDataGrid.Column("Edit",format:@<text>@Html.ActionLink("Edit","EditOrganizationAle","AleCalculation",new{id = Model.OrganizationId},"")</text>)
            ))
</div>
```

Comment: If I had to guess your ID has a bunch of blank spaces on the end of it that is translating to that ascii.  You might try running a trim on the id to see if that helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might try trimming the parameter:

```
new { id = Model.OrganizationId.Trim() }
```

Answer (score 5):

I think the reason for this is the *field type* you specified within the database. You probably use a **char** type with a fixed length (so it will be filled with spaces). If you use **VarChar** instead, it won't append the string with spaces.

Like p.s.w.g said, you can Trim() it, but that's only a work around.

Comment: Well that's good to know. Thanks MS for making a troublesome and pretty much useless data type.

Comment: @scuba the char type is allways the same length, so its startoffset can be calculated easely. Only use this with small lengths. The varchar can be variable length with a maximum. This way youll save space at the cost of indexing.

Comment: Well TSQL has a maximum row length of 8000 something bytes. So if you're dealing with lots of long varchar strings, that could cause you to run into issues, but in-general I'd agree with you.